# Using destruct instead of inversion

Tags: coq, proof, theorem-proving, coq-tactic

I understand the principle of explosion proof using the `inversion` tactic:

```
Theorem ex_falso_quodlibet : forall (P:Prop),
  False -> P.
Proof.
  intros P contra.
  inversion contra.  Qed.
```

However, I don't understand the steps taken by Coq in order to do the same proof but using `destruct` instead of `inversion`:

```
Theorem ex_falso_quodlibet' : forall (P:Prop),
  False -> P.
Proof.
  intros P contra.
  destruct contra.  Qed.
```

How is `False` inductive to be destructed? How does it affect to the goal and complete the proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`False` is an empty inductive data type, i.e. it has no possible values, see [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html). `True` is an inductive data type with a single value `I`

When we `destruct` a value `X` of inductive data type we replace the current goal with multiple subgoals, one per each possible value of `X`. When we destruct `False`, we end up with zero subgoals to prove (as it has zero values), therefore proof is completed.

Basically, `destruct` and `inversion` do more or less the same thing here.

Comment: @Waiting for Dev... Adam Chlipala explains `inversion` and `destruct`  [here](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Predicates.html) in his book CPDT. (Search for the word 'inversion', in the page and you'll get right to it).